# Create a Checkbox for a Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, button, checkbox, window

I searched myself through for about 1 hour only to realise that I might be the biggest beginner, but since everybody must have been at that point in a time, i hope for your patience.

My question: i have an empty Winform which is opened after a button is pressed on a custom created outlook properties button.

the button code:

```
private void FensterOeffnen(object sender, IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
    {
        EinstellungenFenster fenster = new EinstellungenFenster();
        fenster.ShowDialog();
    }
```

the Winform code:

```
public partial class EinstellungenFenster : Form
{   

    public EinstellungenFenster()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();
        Text = "Outlook Add-in Einstellungen";

    }
}
```

**the Reason i need a checkbox:**
i want to implement a popup (Debug so to say) window on each and every method that i have on my Outlook Add-in if the button is checked, so that if the code stopps working at a certain point after deployment, i can still easily tell where the problem is.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: why not put Checkbox on EinstellungenFenster in form designer?

Comment: Thank you @shibornot, i found a great Article, posting the following in here, because of the rules."
Answering my own question instead of deleting it for the sake of what Stackoverflow is about, sake of knowledge, who knows, some other beginner might have it easier to find the answer in the future.

here is the link with a great description:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/checkbox-in-C-Sharp3/

Comment: Just a little advice: You shouldn't write your variable/class names in other languages. The line `if (done)` is a lot easier to read, than the line `if (fertig)`, and when other programmer need to look at your code, they'll understand it a lot faster too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the toolbox on vs by going to view and toolbox then expand all windows forms and scroll down to check-box and drag it on to the form.

and then implement the checked procedure by adding on the button clicked

```
if (Checkboxname.Checked = true)
{
 // Do Stuff when checked
}
```

hope this helps